# *ngIf or [hidden] not working correctly

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to allow for hiding of certain sections of the project I'm working on via user toggle.  It saves in the database and gets pulled when the page is loaded in the constructor using the following code

```
this.http.get(`api/section/get/${this.id}`, this.id).subscribe(res => {
            this.section = res.json()[0];
            this.sect = res.json();
            console.log(this.section);

            this.hideIntro = this.sect[0].hideIntro;
            this.hideMainVideo = this.sect[0].hideMainVideo;
            this.hideHandout = this.sect[0].hideHandout;
            this.hideQuiz = this.sect[0].hideQuiz;

            console.log("Hide Intro = " + this.hideIntro);
            console.log("Hide Main = " + this.hideMainVideo);
            console.log("Hide Handout = " + this.hideHandout);
            console.log("Hide Quiz = " + this.hideQuiz);
});
```

The HTML is as follows...

```
<div class="row classMainBackground col-md-12" *ngIf="!hideIntro">
...content...
</div>
```

For some reason, no matter what I do, whether I change it to *ngIf="hideIntro == false" or even use [hidden]="hideIntro", it is not working.

Even the console logs in the .ts file show up correctly.  Is there a reason why this is not working for me?  I've used it in other positions and it works fine there...

Does it have something to do with assigning it in the constructor or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im guessing here, but is this.sect[0].hideIntro a string? If it is you can try *ngIf="hideIntro === 'false'". Note the '' inside "".

Comment: For debugging, you can show the value of `hideIntro` in the view: `<div>hideIntro: {{hideIntro}} </div>`.

Comment: well, hideIntro is a boolean (bit) in the database, and its defined as a 
hideIntro: boolean;
    hideHandout: boolean;
    hideMainVideo: boolean;
    hideQuiz: boolean;
in the ts file.

I already have the value of hideIntro, this is what the console logs do.  Easier for me to do it that way because the ...content... is actually all my content.  I have also checked if its a string by doing that before, and it does not work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "...content... is all my content". Did you try showing `{{hideIntro}}` in the div? If so, what do you see? It may differ from the `console.log` output; that is why I suggest it.

Comment: it shows something different, you are correct.  It's displaying [object object].  Now just trying to figure out why that's happening and I'm assuming with what someone said below.

Answer (score 3):

Angular change detection runs in response to use interaction with the component. If values are updated outside of that event handling (such as after an HTTP request), you need to manually tell the component that it has changed.

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef){}

this.http.get(`api/section/get/${this.id}`, this.id).subscribe(res => {
    [...]
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
})
```

More in depth reading: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: To be honest with you, I'm not even worried about it changing at all at this point in time.  All I'm worried about is hiding content if the value is true.  From what it seems like you responded, this is for updating certain things after the page has loaded already.  I'm simply just trying to grab data from the database when the page loads, and use ngIf to show/hide that content depending on the boolean value, not worrying about being able to change it afterwards.

Comment: @AlexLiosatos Yep, that's the situation where you need to use this. It's essentially a timing problem. It's easy to think that the code runs `loading starts` -> `http start` -> `http end` -> `page loaded`, but that's incorrect. Because the http request is an asynchronous action, the browser schedules it differently. The code execution is actually `loading starts` -> `http start` -> `page loaded` -> `http end`, so you need to manually tell Angular "Hey something changed"

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the problem by using {{!section.hideIntro}} in the HTML instead of trying to define a new variable to pass that boolean to.

I believe the answer was a combination of what @Vlad274 and @ConnorsFan were mentioning.

the HTML was returning an [object object] for {{hideIntro}} and it seems like there's a delay between the assigning the new value data from the GET response before the DOM actually loads.

Grabbing the data right from the GET respone variable ended up doing the trick.